# How to use JUnit4TestAdapter with objects

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4

I am trying to write a test suite using JUnit4 by relying on JUnit4TestAdapter. Having a look at the [code of this class](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/blob/master/src/main/java/junit/framework/JUnit4TestAdapter.java) I saw that it only works with a Class as input. I would like to build a test class and set a parameter on it before running it with my TestSuite. Unfortunately, Junit4TestAdapter is building the test by using reflection (not 100% sure about the mechanism behind it), which means that I cannot change my test class on runtime.
Has anybody done anything similar before? Is there any possible workaround to this issue? Thanks for your help!

```
public class SimpleTest {
    @Test
    public void testBasic() {
        TemplateTester tester = new TemplateTester();
        ActionIconsTest test = new ActionIconsTest();
        test.setParameter("New Param Value");
        tester.addTests(test);
        tester.run();
    }
}

/////

public class TemplateTester {
    private TestSuite suite;

    public TemplateTester() {
        suite = new TestSuite();
    }   

    public void addTests(TemplateTest... tests) {
        for (TemplateTest test : tests) {
            suite.addTest(new JUnit4TestAdapter(test.getClass()));
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        suite.run(new TestResult());
    }
}

/////

public interface TemplateTest {

}

/////

public class ActionIconsTest extends BaseTestStrategy implements TemplateTest {

    @Test
    public void icons() {
        //Test logic here
    }

    public void navigateToTestPage() {
        //Here I need the parameter
    }
}

/////

public abstract class BaseTestStrategy {
    protected String parameter;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        navigateToTestPage();
    }

    public abstract void navigateToTestPage();

    public void setParameter(String parameter) {
        this.parameter = parameter;
    }    
}
```

I am trying to test a web application with Selenium. The way I want to test is by splitting the functionality, e.g., I want to test the available icons (ActionIconsTest), then I'd like to test other parts like buttons, etc.
The idea behind this is to have a better categorization of the functionality available in certain screen. This is quite coupled with the way we are currently developing our web app.

With this in mind, TemplateTest is just an interface implemented by the different kind of tests (ActionIconTest, ButtonTest, etc) available in my system.
TemplateTester is a Junit suite test with all the different tests that implement the interface TemplateTest.

**The reason for this question is because I was trying to implement a Strategy pattern and then realized of the inconvenient of passing a class to Junit4TestAdapter in runtime.**

Comment: Could you give us some background on the larger problem that you are trying to solve? What is `TemplateTest`? What's `ActionIconsTest`? What's `TemplateTester` used for? Why is `TemplateTester` called from a JUnit test but also uses JUnit classes?

Comment: I added an update on the bottom of my question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, taking in account that JUNIT needs your tester's Class object as an object factory (so he can create *several instances* of your tester), I can only suggest you pass parameters to your tester through System Properties.

Moreover, it's the recommended way of passing parameters: http://junit.org/faq.html#running_7

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added some code, maybe now it is more clear what I want to achieve.